# Getting a specific element from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, yahoo-finance

This is probably a rookie question, but I haven't been able to find the solution.

I'm trying to collect some data from Yahoo Finance using pandas.

```
from pandas_datareader import data

tickers = ['EQNR.OL','BP','CL=F']
start_date = '2001-01-02'
end_date = '2021-02-26'
panel_data = data.DataReader(tickers, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
```

I wanna take a look at the BP stock (I need all 3, so excluding EQNR.OL and CL=F from `tickers` is not the right solution). I know how to get all the close prices of a single stock:
`close_BP = panel_data['Close','BP']`

But is there a way I can get all BP data (open, close, high, low) withdrawn from 'panel_data', and not only a specific column like 'close'?
I was thinking something like `BP = panel_data[:,'BP']`  or `BP = panel_data.loc[:,'BP']` but it doesn't work.

A big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is **pandas.IndexSlice**...

```py
import pandas as pd
panel_data.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'BP']]
```

Comment: Exactly! That does the trick, thank you @Icarwiz.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap multi-columns and then extract them with loc.

```
panel_data = panel_data.swaplevel(axis=1)
panel_data.loc[:, ('BP',)]

Attributes  Adj Close   Close       High        Low           Open      Volume
Date                        
2021-01-04  20.551737   20.830000   21.129999   20.549999   21.090000   14485100.0
2021-01-05  22.081030   22.379999   22.780001   21.370001   21.430000   25447500.0
2021-01-06  23.097271   23.410000   23.860001   22.940001   23.370001   25221400.0
2021-01-07  23.590591   23.910000   24.150000   23.500000   23.719999   16470700.0
2021-01-08  24.074045   24.400000   24.490000   23.990000   24.170000   20189600.0
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really useful feature that I didn't knew about.